# Ifstream doesn't work

Tags: c++, std, ifstream

Here is my code.

```
std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (file.fail());
    {
        fatalError("File could not be opened.");
    }
```

This doesn't give me a build error, however it doesn't want to open the file. I am trying to open a PNG file, but it fails every time.

Comment: Remove the semicolon after the if.

Comment: You should enable warnings, [they tend to tell you these things](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2872aa1890185231).

Answer (score 4):

You have a semicolon after the `if`, which is forcing that if statement to be (effectively) ignored completely. The expression in the braces is being evaluated unconditionally after the `if` is ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel like such an idiot right now.